# Why implicit conversion from strongly typed enum to its underlying type is not allowed?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums

Let's consider the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>

enum class foo_bar : unsigned
{
    foo,
    bar,
};

int main()
{
    foo_bar bar = foo_bar::bar;
    // unsigned a = bar; -- error: cannot convert ‘foo_bar’ to ‘unsigned int’ in initialization
    unsigned a = static_cast<std::underlying_type<foo_bar>::type>(bar);
    return 0;
}
```

Why the implicit conversion is not allowed? The underlying type is known, type of `a` matches the `foo_bar` underlying type. The implicit conversion seems to be safe and could be performed without losing an information. Why the cast is necessary from the language design perspective?

Comment: Because that's the whole point?

Comment: >strongly typed >implicit cast

Comment: @Xeo: came to leave the same comment and you beaten me to it, aww :)

Comment: "I'm using a feature to prevent me from doing X, and I'm wondering – why can't I do X using this feature?"

Comment: "Strongly typed" sounds like it should give an idea for why it works this way.

Comment: @Ven: It's pretty clear why I'm unable to cast `unsigned` to `foo_bar` implicitly (because such a cast potentially loses information), but why `foo_bar` to `unsigned` is not allowed?

Comment: @ivaigult Because `enum class`es aren't `unsigned` and the fact they're represented with a specific integral type is irrelevant

Comment: Let me rephrase. You're using a feature that gives you a strongly-typed enum. And your question here is: "why is my enum strongly-typed"?

Comment: @Ven: If something is strongly type it doesn't necessary imply that implicit cast is not allowed. A c++ class is strongly typed, but I may define a cast operator or proper constructor in another class and implicit cast becomes available for me but the class is still strongly typed. Am I missing something? Is there any definition of "strongly-typed" type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [N2347](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2347.pdf), the problem with implicit integral promotion is that you can compare two different enums:

```
enum Color { ClrRed, ClrOrange, ClrYellow, ClrGreen, ClrBlue, ClrViolet };
enum Alert { CndGreen, CndYellow, CndRed };
Color c = ClrGreen;
Alert a = CndGreen;
bool armWeapons = ( a >= c ); // compiles but does not make sense
```

To see what is really going here, you can emulate enum classes with structures:

```
struct A {
    operator int() const {
        // for simplicity, just return fixed value
        return 1;
    }
};

struct B {
    operator int() const {
        return 2;
    }
};

A a;
B b;
int i = b; // ok
bool x = (a < b); // yay, this compiles
```

Now, the correct solution would be to make the operators `explicit`:

```
struct B {
    explicit operator int() const {
        return 2;
    }
};

A a;
B b;
bool x = (a < b); // finally does not work
int i = b; // but now this does not work without explicit cast either
```